# Registering with different email types

Tags: php

I want the user to register using their student email address, the code i have is only for one college and i want to have 6 different colleges.

```
        if(!preg_match('/^x[\d]{8}@student\.ncirl\.ie$/', $email)){ // forcing exact email
            // Return Error - Invalid Email
            $error = true;
            $emailError = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.';
        } 
        else{
            // check email exist or not
            $res = $conn->prepare("SELECT userEmail FROM users WHERE userEmail = ?");
            $res -> execute([$email]);
            $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $count = $res->rowCount();

            if($count !== 0){
                $error = true;
                $emailError = "Provided Email is already in use.";
            }
        }
    // EMAIL VALIDATION
```

Comment: Okay, so what's your question?

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all.

Comment: my question is i want the user to register with their student email and i only have one of the colleges, i want to add different colleges emails

Comment: @Alex - That's still not a question. It's a statement saying what you want. A question would be: _"How do I...?"_, _"Why...?"_ or something similar (that ends with a question mark). The problem with your "question" is that you haven't told us where exactly you're stuck. You've only given a broad statement of what you want.

Comment: @CBroe sorry if you dont get what i meant .. i'm doing a website for third level student for different colleges and i want the student to register with their student email. i added one student email and its working perfectly but i want to add other student email from different colleges like: ('/^x[\d]{8}@student\.ncirl\.ie$/', $email) ('/^x[\d]{8}@student\.dit\.ie$/', $email) - but this is not working for me

Comment: I recommend you create a function to validate the email, then you can call to this function only pass the email as parameter exampe -> validate_email($my_email);

Answer (score 2):

If you’re just wanting to validate the domain portion, then you can expand your regular expression to use a group:

```php
if (preg_match('/^(.*)@(college1.edu|college2.edu|college3.edu)$/', $submitted_email)) {
    // Email is one of the three
}
```

The difficulty comes with if each university has different formats for the user portion, as in your example I can see you’re checking if the email address begins with the letter “x” and then eight numbers. You may be better off defining an array of formats to check, and looping over them:

```php
$formats = [
    '/^x\d{8}@student\.ncirl\.ie$/',
    '/^user.[a-z]+@some.other.college.edu$/',
    // and so on
];

$valid = false;

foreach ($formats as $format) {
    if (preg_match($format, $submitted_email)) {
        $valid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($valid) {
    // Do rest of registration logic
}
```

Comment: If in future there will be collages added, its not suggestible you keep changing the code every time. Better store them in db and fetch them in a array. When you need to validate, check if the domain name of the email is present in the array or not. Hope that adds some value to the above answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin thats exactly what i wanted .. its working perfectly now